# How to create a hexagon world map in PHP from a database for a browser based strategy game

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a hexagon world map for my PHP browser based strategy game. I've created a table in my database with the following data per row: id, type, x, y and occupied. Where type is the kind of tiles, which are defined in numbers. For example, 1 is grass. The map itself is 25 x 25.

I want to draw the map from the database with clickable tiles and the possibilty to navigate through the map with arrows. I don't really have a clue on how to start with this and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Fabian

---

I understand I have to use Javascript with this, but I have still no clue on creating the arrays for loading the tiles and coordinates from the database and display them with javascript on the page.

Comment: My advice would be to start at the beginning. :-)  In all seriousness, I suspect you'll get a better response to this question (if there isn't already an answer) over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is a little broad of a request for SO...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow, and didn't knew there was also a gamedev section. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your asking about a hex grid, a very good [introduction to generating hexgrid tiles using Javascript](http://www.ronsbrain.com/hexmap.html) can be found by Ron Martin

[image]

From that point forward, you'll just have to handle the click events to utilize your PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely going to need some javascript code for that. I would recommend using jQuery as e framework. It has all you need: event capturing(click, button pressed), DOM manipulation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw the hexagons with javascript, as pictures will not work if you put them next to each other. Draw the shapes with javascript, then capture clicks inside them. This might help: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm